# How to know when the user has closed the Android application?

Tags: android

Is there any way of finding when an application is closed (either by user or system) i.e the application can only be restarted by the user by pressing the application launcher icon.

I think it is only possible if Android system broadcast any Intent when a name of a process is removed from [getRunningAppProcesses()](http://pages.citebite.com/q8d0d8f8ouey).

I have read all the possible Q&A on the SO and the question is not related with the ActivityLifecycle.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  The user *doesn't* close the application.  Trying to monitor and restart an app after the user kills it is a bad idea.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski I am not trying to restart the application after user has exit it. I need to update a Db from a Webservice but I want to do it after the user has exited the application in background.

Comment: you want it after  user close  an activity or application? kill you mean from process manager? or just press back?

Comment: @coding crow: the user *still* doesn't exit the application, they simply let it go to the background.  You should do this in a way that respects the semantics of the application.  What if the user never exits the app?

Comment: Maybe sending a message in the activity's onStop-method to the service that will do the update in background. And keep in mind that the user might restart/reenter the application during your update...

Comment: @KristopherMicinski I could not understand "user doesn't exit the application?" Can you help me understand?

Comment: @codingcrow the user never exits the application!  When the user leaves the app it is still present in memory, still in the background, still running, it just isn't on the screen!

Comment: @KristopherMicinski That is the case when `onPause()` is called if `onDestroy()` is called on all activities does application still run in background?

Comment: @codingcrow you have no guarantee as to this, or if it will ever happen.  Waiting for an application to "exit" before you do something to its database is a bad idea: you should do it in a way consistent with the semantics of the application instead.

Comment: @TobiN Yes you are right when you say "user might restart/reenter the application during the update" Do you have ant other solution in mind? I don't have solution to this problem.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Agreed. Can you put thoughts in the answer, or would you want me to ask another question?

Comment: I think what @codingcrow is saying is that he want to do some update in a database that live in some WebService somewhere.  So prosumably he has some application which monitors the list of application running on a device, and when the one he cares about goes away for whatever reason, he then does his WebService call to update his DB that lives somewhere in the cloud.  But thats just my guess.  codingcrow,  you should provide some more details about your architecture

Comment: @AkosCz I have a ListFragment which shows a list people from a Content Provider which in turn in updated by a database on the Web. Now the Content provider need to be updated/synchronized with DB on web once in a while but I don't want to update this ListFragment while a user is interacting with it.

Comment: Sorry to say, but your going down the wrong rabbit hole.  The solution  to you are seeking for your problem will most likely not involve monitoring if your application has been killed by the OS (ie: PID gone for the process list)

Comment: It sounds like you need a backrgound service which keeps your database and content provider in sync.  As for your ListFragment, you load it with the data that is available from the content provider upon construction time.

Comment: @codingcrow that's a horrible idea: the concept of database watchers were invented specifically for this purpose, you just design your app so that it updates with the remote database, and then define the semantics of interaction properly for interaction after the database has been updated.  You should look at a `ContentObserver`

Comment: @AkosCz Agreed. The architecture is more complex than what I have described, I need to rethink all over for sure Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm..  You can manually monitor /proc on the filesystem to see if the process id is present for the application you care about.

From your terminal window try the following.  For example :

```
> MYPID=(`adb shell ps | grep com.mydomain.myapp | awk '{print $2}'`)
> adb shell [ -d /proc/$MYPID ] && echo "PID $MYPID Exists"
```

Replace *com.mydomain.myapp* with your apps package name

There are several apps available to monitor processes on android.
Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-os-monitor/

The android-os-monitor project uses a JNI layer to implement the interaction with /proc
http://code.google.com/p/android-os-monitor/source/browse/OSMonitor/jni/process.c?repo=osmonitor

http://code.google.com/p/android-os-monitor/source/browse/OSMonitor/src/com/eolwral/osmonitor/JNIInterface.java?repo=osmonitor

http://code.google.com/p/android-os-monitor/source/browse/OSMonitor/src/com/eolwral/osmonitor/processes/ProcessList.java?repo=osmonitor

Answer (score 4):

Generally, waiting for a user to "exit" an app is a bad idea, since:

- The user never actually exists the app, they simply leave it on the activity stack and come back to it later.
- A user might do anything during your database update, such as reenter the app.
- You can't really detect this without very hacky solutions; this is by *design* of the API, because you shouldn't *need* to do these kinds of things.

Because of this, I think any solution based on waiting for the app to "die" is a bad one.  Instead, you should come up with a solution that respects the semantics of the application.  For example, if you are entering data in one of its content providers then it should handle consistency (across fragments in the app, for example).